# TestLink and Trac Integration

Tags: php, trac, testlink

this is my situation. I have TestLink 1.9.7 installed and working, along with Trac installed and working on the same machine. I'm trying to get the two to integrate, but I'm having some difficulty. I was able to install the XMLRPC plugin (I had an issue where easy_install was giving an index error, so I downloaded the zipped source and installed from there, which worked), and made the following changes:

On custom_config.inc.php, I added the line:

```
$g_interface_bugs = 'TRAC';
```

And on trac.cfg.php, I added the lines:

```
define('BUG_TRACK_DB_HOST', 'http://localhost:8000/trac');
define('BUG_TRACK_XMLRPC_HOST', 'http://user:pass@localhost');
$g_interface_bugs_project_name_mapping = array('TLProj' => 'TracProject');
```

On trac.ini, I added the lines:

```
[components]
tracrpc.* = enabled
```

And yet, I don't see an option in TL's Issue Tracker Management to even create the Issue Tracker for Trac. Help, please!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the user running the xmlrpc have XML_RPC permission in Trac? Check with `trac-admin C:/your/trac/instance permission list`

Comment: You should also check the Apache log file if your PHP script has tried to access the Trac system

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the answer man, i too had the same problem.
After doing all the steps you mentioned, go the testlink UI and do the following:

- Step 1

Select project and Click issue tracker management

- Step 2

Enter issue tracker name, select type, and in the configuration section enter the following

```
<!-- Template tracxmlrpcInterface -->
<issuetracker>
<username>USERNAME</username>
<password>PASSWORD</password>
<uribase>'http://<YourTracServer>/<YourTracProjectName</uribase>
</issuetracker>
```

- Step 3

Go to test project management, select the project and select issue tracker and click active